# I am getting an error for importing replit

Tags: python, discord, replit, replit-database

```
--> poetry add replit
Using version ^3.3.2 for replit

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...

Because no versions of replit match >3.3.2,<4.0.0
 and replit (3.3.2) depends on Flask (>=2.0.0,<3.0.0), replit (>=3.3.2,<4.0.0) requires Flask (>=2.0.0,<3.0.0).
So, because python-template depends on both flask (^3.0.0) and replit (^3.3.2), version solving failed.
exit status 1
```

I am using python 3.10 . I am trying to import replit database but everytime i import replit in my code this error pops up. Please help me guys

Answer (score 1):

Replit 3.3.2 depends on Flask 2.0.0, but the python-template project you're using requires Flask 3.0.0. If python-template is a new poetry package you're developing (as it's not present in pypi), you can restrict the Flask version to 2.0.0 in your pyproject file before adding replit.